# Xcode 7 UIWebView doesn't load url

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview

I use UIWebView in my app and it all worked fine in Xcode4,5,6 simulator. but not for Xcode 7 simulator, I don't know why, there is no warning or error in simulator, and the screen is just showing blank page. Please help me. Thanks.

```
#import "IndexViewController.h"

@interface IndexViewController ()

@end

@implementation IndexViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *urlString = nil;
    NSString *languageCode = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
    if ([languageCode isEqualToString:@"zh-Hans"]) {
        urlString = @"http://www.originoftime.net/index-cn";
    }else if ([languageCode isEqualToString:@"zh-Hant"]) {
        urlString = @"http://www.originoftime.net/index-cn";
    }else{
        urlString = @"http://www.originoftime.net/index-en";
    }
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLRequest *urlrequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [_Index loadRequest:urlrequest];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Xcode 7 with iOS9 now force you to not use HTTP call, but HTTPS ones.

this is a security point enhanced in AppTransportSecurity.

Try this:

- Go to your info.plist
- Add a dictionary called NSAppTransportSecurity
- Add a boolean attribute to this one, called NSAllowsArbitraryLoads
- Pass it to TRUE

Reload your app.

I advice you that if Apple want to block HTTP (unsecured) calls is for a good reason. http://www.originoftime.net/index-cn has a HTTPS one but the server certificate seems to be self-signed.

Let me know if this workaround work for you

Cheers from france

Comment: For more details, I advice you to read this complete article: [WORKING WITH APPLE’S APP TRANSPORT SECURITY](http://www.neglectedpotential.com/2015/06/working-with-apples-application-transport-security/)

Comment: Since people might still be looking at this answer: Apple officially announced that they will stop automatically accepting App Store submissions with ATS exemptions (the NSAppTransportSecurity keys in info.plist). This was during the WWDC 2016 session "What's New in Security". The speaker mentioned that app submissions with a reasonable justification may still use ATS exemptions.

Comment: @DylanS you're right ! but nothing concrete for now, except a sentence in the keynote file of this session :/ ! 
For all: As i said when i wrote my answer, you might not shunt this ATS, but rather check out your certificate (like self-signed: booo for production)

Answer (score 1):

Do you implement the web view delegate methods? In particular:

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
```

If a load fails, that will tell you what the issue is.

It could well be the error related to the new security model which is being enforced for network access. You can override this new behavior by adding the following into your Info.plist file. Just edit the XML and paste this in:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
<dict> 
   <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>  
</dict>
```

The changes are summarized here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/index.html