# WKWebView blank after 'successful' HTTPS NSURLRequest

Tags: ios, swift, https, uiwebview, wkwebview

I have created a NSURLRequest (HTTPS)

The delegate callbacks for the WKWebView come back with success, no error.

'decidePolicyForNavigationAction' is provided with the Allow Enum in the decision handler

```
   @available(iOS 8.0, *)
    func webView(webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyForNavigationAction navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {

        decisionHandler(.Allow)

    }
```

and the didReceiveAuthChallenge is handled as such:

```
@available(iOS 8.0, *)
func webView(webView: WKWebView, didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge,
    completionHandler: (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential?) -> Void) {
        let cred = NSURLCredential.init(forTrust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!)
        completionHandler(.UseCredential, cred)
        print("Did receive auth challenge")
}
```

as i get no error after`'didFinishNavigation'` I'm unsure whats going wrong as my WebView is still blank? If i use UIWebView i get the correct webpage showing?

Cheers,

Comment: Did you add the `WKWebView` to your view hierarchy? If you are going to default to `.UseCredential` then you can also simply not implement the second delegate method.

Comment: @StefanArentz yeah definitely on the hierarchy - just not happening :( it will show https://www.google.com but not http://www.google.com - but will show www.apple.com and https://www.apple.com

Comment: Do you implement `didFailNavigation:withError` and `didFailProvisionalNavigation:withError`? If not implement these to detect errors. From the links that work, they seem to be https URLS. The one that does not is an http URL. There is a new security feature in iOS9 which fails to load http URLS unless they conform to special rules or you setup xcode to override the new feature. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32719032/xcode-7-uiwebview-doesnt-load-url/32719408#32719408

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel yes implemented this but i get no errors back. Whilst Im aware of this new HTTPS feature ill give a check if this makes a difference. thanks :)

Comment: A tool that is worth trying for debugging what is going on is Charles (http://www.charlesproxy.com/). If you have not used it, it acts as a proxy for all web traffic so you can see all the requests and responses. Handy for knowing what UIWebView/WkWebView is actually doing under the hood. Might or might not show you anything. Free trial version which is handy for a quick debug.

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel got Charles running anyway as makes life easy behind a huge cooperate proxy so I'll have a look :) thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To detect errors you should make sure you implement `didFailNavigation:withError` and `didFailProvisionalNavigation:withError`.

From the links that work, they seem to be https URLs. The one that does not is an http URL. Implementing the above error methods should tell you what is wrong.

There is a new security feature in iOS9 which fails to load HTTP URLs unless the server conforms to specific set of rules or you setup xcode to override the new feature. You can override the new feature by adding the following into your Info.plist file. Just paste the following at the bottom:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
<dict> 
   <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>  
</dict>
```

This overrides all of the new functionality. You can however perform more specific overrides. The Apple tech note on the changes is here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/index.html

Comment: Cheers but got the NSAppTransportSecurity entry in my plist as no errors are fired :-( just the finished navigation one! Boo, at present I've gone back to UIWebView

Comment: @theiOSDude If I create a new project with a WKWebView and try and load http://www.google.com, `didFailProvisionalNavigation:withError` fires with the ATS error. When I update the Info.plist with the noted changes, it works fine. Works in both ObjC and Swift. Are you sure you have implemented this delegate and also update the plist properly?

Comment: Not working. Still showing blank white screen after "successfully" request js target=”_blank“.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem too but found this solution in a training video:

1. Add a Dictionary Key to your info.plist with the following name: 
   NSAppTransportSecurity
2. Create a Boolean subkey to that with the name
   NSAllowsArbitraryLoads and set to TRUE.

After that it worked here.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your WKWebView frame is set to a positive height in viewDidLoad, because otherwise the webview has no height and does not seem to resize itself after loading:

```
_webView =[[WKWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height )];
```